# Given two empirical distribution A and B, how to setup a hypothesis test to test if a new data point is from distribution A?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, empirical-likelihood

I have two empirical distribution A and B (i.e. two continuous datasets in $\mathcal{R}$) and I am trying to set up a hypothesis test to test if a new data point is from distribution A.  Naturally this calls for a likelihood ratio test.  I was planning on setting the test as
$$
H_0: \text{the new data point is from distribution A}
$$
$$
H_1: \text{the new data point is from distribution B}
$$
The likelihood ratio can be computed as
$$
\frac{P(H_0|x)}{P(H_1|x)} = \frac{P(H_0)}{P(H_1)}\frac{P(x|H_0)}{P(x|H_1)}
$$
However, I am not sure how I would compute the likelihood $P(x|H_0)$ and $P(x|H_1)$ here, given that A and B are empirical distribution in continuous space.  I could compute the empirical CDF but I am not sure how to convert that to an empirical PDF.  Should I consider fitting some kind of kernel density and use them as the likelihood?